# Resize image over "orbit" with Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, photoshop-effects

I'm using photoshop CC 2015 and I'd like to "resize" a music score line around an object in an orbit fashion (perhaps not completely horizontal, diagonal would be better), I'll give you an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish with my *mad paint sk1llz*

[image]

The object is already in place, but I have no idea how to resize a music score line that way.

Can someone shed some light on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: You do not want to *resize*, you want to *wrap*, *bend*, or *map*!

I never worked with Photoshop, but it seems like you should be able to use the following aproach. This explanation is for Gimp:

1. Draw your music sheet line on a transparent layer
   [image: music sheet line]
2. In Gimp: Select the layer with the music line and use `Filters > Map > Map Object...` to map your line onto the surface of a cylinder. In this dialog, you can also rotate the cylinder to your needs. Photoshop's equivalent seems to be `3D > New Mesh from Layer > Mesh Preset > Cylinder`
   [image: Gimp's "map to object"]
3. The result should look like this. As you can see, my music sheet line was a bit short. The line should be a lot longer so that it won't be stretched.
   [image: mapped line]
4. Put the orbit over the planet.
   [image: mapped line + sphere]
5. Use the selection tool or the eraser to remove the parts of the orbit which should be occluded by the planet.
   [image: erased occluded parts]

Photoshop also has other tools which can be used to achieve the desired effect, for instace the warp tool.